# How to remove everything from a string and leave behind only digits ( something faster than *** re.sub('[^0-9]', '', str) ***)?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I run this line to remove everything but the digits from a string.

```
str = "a111.113ç"
str = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', str)
```

but perhaps having to ..

```
import re
```

might be slowing things down..

is there a more speedy version of this without importing re ?

**UPDATE**

perhaps i should find out what is inside of "re" and then bring that over to my script by copy pasting the function directly into my script ?

Comment: Is that really not fast enough? Have a benchmark setup so that other answers can be compared for "faster"? In any case, consider this trivial changes: 1) use `re.compile` to build the regular expression *once* (assumes it is run many times within the same process), and 2) use `'[^0-9]+'` as it *might* help in cases of many non-digits in a row. Compare the changes of these results with the benchmark. Wait, no benchmark? Go back to the start of this comment. (I seriously doubt `import re` or a single regular expression usage are the "slowdown", whatever it is.)

Comment: May be your problem is Python startup time? Probably the best solution is to change a bit the problem and leaving Python running... for example instead of reading/generating lines and starting a new fresh Python for each line let do Python the reading or use piping

Answer (score 1):

Using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), "a111.113ç")
'111113'
```

BTW, don't use `str` as a variable name. It will shadow a builtin function/type [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: @user2864740, In the question, OP wrote `without importing re`.

Comment: The OP is all sorts of confused .. but true statement.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use `filter`:

```
filter(lambda x: 47 < ord(x) < 58, str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed, `re` is probably the best choice. Python is not very fast in making iterations so it is best to rely an some library which is dedicated and optimized for this task.

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster than a regex:

```
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, '3,14%_56'))
'31456'
```

Another possibility is to use *str.translate()*:

```
>>> delchars = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256) if not chr(i).isdigit())
>>> '3,14%_56'.translate(None, delchars)
```

Comment: Why should it be faster? Have a program demonstrating such timings? If it's a single run, make sure to include the relevant Python startup overhead. If it's many runs, don't forget to compile the regular expression.